# How to exclude gitlab-ci.yml changes from triggering a job

Tags: gitlab, gitlab-ci, cicd, gitlab-ci-trigger

I am unable to find a solution for how to ignore changes made in .gitlab-ci.yml to trigger a job. So far I have tried the below options:

```
except:
  changes:
  - .gitlab-ci.yml
```

and

```
only
 - Branch A
```

but every time i make changes in .gitlab.ci-yml file, jobs for Stage B get added in pipeline and show as skipped.

Below are the jobs defined in .gitlab-ci.yml. Do you have any suggestion here?

I do not want Stage B jobs get added in pipeline when:

i) push made against the .gitlab-ci.yml (either manual changing file or `git push` command)
ii) any merge request for .gitlab-ci.yml

```
stages:
 - A
 - B
 
Stage A:
  stage: A
  script:
    - echo "TEST"
  rules:
    - if: '$CI_COMMIT_TAG =~ /^\d+\.\d+\.DEV\d+/'
  tags:
    - runner
    
Stage B:
  stage: B
  script:
    - echo "TEST"
  when: manual
  tags:
    - runner
```

Comment: What's the output when you add the 'except' rule?

Comment: that except rule does not get invoked, and job gets added in pipeline.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

With this setup the `Stage B` is not added if `.gitlab-ci.yml` is modified:

```
stages:
 - A
 - B

Stage A:
  stage: A
  script:
    - echo "Stage A"
  tags:
    - runner

Stage B:
  stage: B
  script:
    - echo "Stage B"
  rules:
    - changes:
      - ".gitlab-ci.yml"
      when: never
    - when: manual
  tags:
   - runner
```

Otherwise `Stage B` is showed in the pipeline and can be run manually. Tested with GitLab CI CE 14.1.0.

Comment: But will it still shows manual button option for other file push/merge changes?

Comment: Yes, as I wrote and tested, the manual job `Stage B` is displayed if at least one file but `.gitlab-ci.yml` is modified.

Answer (score 1):

Could you try using [`workflow`](https://docs.gitlab.com/ee/ci/yaml/#workflow) rule? It should determine if the pipeline is created.

P.S: Someone complained [a couple of years ago](https://forum.gitlab.com/t/run-pipeline-manually-with-except-changes/23234/6) about not being able to activate manual jobs after the exception, but it looks like it was a bug. I can't find the issue mentioned in the post

Edit:

This conf skips any commit with changes `README.md` or `.gitlab-ci.yml`:

```
workflow:
    rules:
        - if:
          changes: 
            - README.md
            - .gitlab-ci.yml
          when: never
```

Comment: but job will still get added in pipeline for other files push/merges changes ? please advise.

Comment: For every push that doesn't modify any of the files listed in `changes`, yes.

Comment: Tried this , pipeline never get triggered irrespective of the whereever the changes are made